# How do you use NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, ios4, nsattributedstring, textcolor

Multiple colours in an `NSString` or `NSMutableStrings` are not possible. So I've heard a little about the [**`NSAttributedString`**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which was introduced with the **iPad SDK 3.2** (or around 3.2) and is available on the iPhone as of **iPhone SDK 4.0 beta**.

I would like to have a string that has three colours.

The reason I don't use 3 separate NSStrings, is because the length of each of the three `NSAttributedString` substrings changes often and so I would prefer, not to use any calculations to re-position 3 separate `NSString` objects.

If it's possible using `NSAttributedString` how do I make the following - (if not possible with NSAttributed string how would you do it):

[image]

**Edit:**
Remember, `@"first"`, `@"second"` and `@"third"` will be replaced by other strings at any time. So using hardcoded NSRange values won't work.

Comment: [Attributed strings in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/3681880)

Comment: The Swift code for NSAttributeString : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift/27728516#27728516

Answer (score 486, accepted):

When building attributed strings, I prefer to use the mutable subclass, just to keep things cleaner.

That being said, here's how you create a tri-color attributed string:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"firstsecondthird"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];
```

<sub>typed in a browser. *caveat implementor*</sub>

Obviously you're not going to hard-code in the ranges like this.  Perhaps instead you could do something like:

```
NSDictionary *wordToColorMapping = ....;  //an NSDictionary of NSString => UIColor pairs
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
for (NSString *word in wordToColorMapping) {
  UIColor *color = [wordToColorMapping objectForKey:word];
  NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:color forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
  NSAttributedString *subString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:word attributes:attributes];
  [string appendAttributedString:subString];
  [subString release];
}

//display string
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. This should work, looks like I just need to replace the hardcoded `NSMakeRange` values with `NSMakeRange(0,[string length])` etc,etc for each string. +1

Comment: @Jack search the docs for "setAttributed". That will let you know about most controls that accept attributed strings

Comment: Can you please let me know how to assign attributed string to the label?

Comment: same question here?? can any one please write a code for assigning attributed string to label ?

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi There's nothing built-in to UIKit that accepts an `NSAttributedString`.  However, there are open source things, such as [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

Comment: If you're using CoreText.framework on iOS, you'll probably want the constant `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` rather than `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Comment: @PhilCalvin Why exactly? Wouldn't `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` wrap nicely around the CoreText constant?

Comment: @SpacyRicochet `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is not defined on iOS, at least if you're compiling against the 5.1 SDK. For MacOS, it's defined in ApplicationKit.

Comment: In iOS6, which was just released (so I can talk without NDA), you can do things like myLabel.attributedText = attributedString; It's about freaking time... I've been waiting for this feature for years.

Comment: I used it but it made my label in one line. I make numberOfLines as 2 from both IB and code but no effect. Setting .text property works fine (shows sentences in 2 lines) but by setting attributedText property of UILabel make it one line. Any one having the same prob? and any solutions?

Comment: Anyway to get the attributes out of a NSAttributedString later? I need to render coloured text using another engine.

Comment: @Jonny `-[NSAttributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:]`

Comment: WARN: Dictionary keys are unordered. Do not use the code above, you will loose control over the order of your strings being displayed.

Comment: `Caveat implementor` is a phrase I will be using in the near future.

Comment: @Matt-Lloyd the two NSDictionaries he's using in his examples are for the word->color mapping and the attributes on each NSAttributedString.  The order of the words is unaffected.

Comment: when i drift the range start pointer > than 0 app crashes for getting out of bounds!

Answer (score 118):

The question is already answered... but I wanted to show how to add shadow and change the font with NSAttributedString as well, so that when people search for this topic they won't have to keep looking.

```
#define FONT_SIZE 20
#define FONT_HELVETICA @"Helvetica-Light"
#define BLACK_SHADOW [UIColor colorWithRed:40.0f/255.0f green:40.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:0.4f]

NSString*myNSString = @"This is my string.\nIt goes to a second line.";                

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
               paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
             paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = FONT_SIZE/2;
                     UIFont * labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_HELVETICA size:FONT_SIZE];
                   UIColor * labelColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
                       NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
                 [shadow setShadowColor : BLACK_SHADOW];
                [shadow setShadowOffset : CGSizeMake (1.0, 1.0)];
            [shadow setShadowBlurRadius : 1];

NSAttributedString *labelText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString : myNSString
                      attributes : @{
   NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
             NSKernAttributeName : @2.0,
             NSFontAttributeName : labelFont,
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : labelColor,
           NSShadowAttributeName : shadow }];
```

Here is a Swift version...

Warning! 
This works for 4s.

For 5s you have to change all of the the Float values to Double values (because the compiler isn't working correctly yet)

Swift enum for font choice:

```
enum FontValue: Int {
    case FVBold = 1 , FVCondensedBlack, FVMedium, FVHelveticaNeue, FVLight, FVCondensedBold, FVLightItalic, FVUltraLightItalic, FVUltraLight, FVBoldItalic, FVItalic
}
```

Swift array for enum access (needed because enum can't use '-'):

```
func helveticaFont (index:Int) -> (String) {
    let fontArray = [
    "HelveticaNeue-Bold",
    "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack",
    "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
    "HelveticaNeue",
    "HelveticaNeue-Light",
    "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",
    "HelveticaNeue-LightItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",
    "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic",
    "HelveticaNeue-Italic",
    ]
    return fontArray[index]
}
```

Swift attributed text function:

```
func myAttributedText (myString:String, mySize: Float, myFont:FontValue) -> (NSMutableAttributedString) {

    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.textShadowColor()
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (1.0, 1.0)
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 1

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    let labelFont = UIFont(name: helveticaFont(myFont.toRaw()), size: mySize)
    let labelColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let myAttributes :Dictionary = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                              NSKernAttributeName : 3, // (-1,5)
                                              NSFontAttributeName : labelFont,
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName : labelColor,
                                            NSShadowAttributeName : shadow]

    let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString (string: myString, attributes:myAttributes)

    // add new color 
    let secondColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let stringArray = myString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    let firstString: String? = stringArray.first
    let letterCount = countElements(firstString!)
    if firstString {
        myAttributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:secondColor], range:NSMakeRange(0,letterCount))
    }

    return  myAttributedString
}
```

first and last extension used for finding ranges in a string array:

```
extension Array {
    var last: T? {
        if self.isEmpty {
            NSLog("array crash error - please fix")
            return self [0]
        } else {
            return self[self.endIndex - 1]
        }
    }
}

extension Array {
    var first: T? {
        if self.isEmpty {
            NSLog("array crash error - please fix")
            return self [0]
        } else {
            return self [0]
        }
    }
}
```

new colors:

```
extension UIColor {
    class func shadowColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3)
    }
    class func textShadowColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)
    }
    class func pastelBlueColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 176.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
    class func pastelYellowColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 238.0/255.0, blue: 140.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

my macro replacement:

```
enum MyConstants: Float {
    case CornerRadius = 5.0
}
```

my button maker w/attributed text:

```
func myButtonMaker (myView:UIView) -> UIButton {

    let myButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.pastelBlueColor()
    myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true;
    let myCGSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(100.0, 50.0)
    let myFrame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.midX - myCGSize.height,myView.frame.midY - 2 * myCGSize.height,myCGSize.width,myCGSize.height)
    myButton.frame = myFrame
    let myTitle = myAttributedText("Button",20.0,FontValue.FVLight)
    myButton.setAttributedTitle(myTitle, forState:.Normal)

    myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.bounds.size.width / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw()
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    myButton.tag = 100
    myButton.bringSubviewToFront(myView)
    myButton.layerGradient()

    myView.addSubview(myButton)

    return  myButton
}
```

my UIView/UILabel maker w/attributed text, shadow, and round corners:

```
func myLabelMaker (myView:UIView) -> UIView {

    let myFrame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.midX / 2 , myView.frame.midY / 2, myView.frame.width/2, myView.frame.height/2)
    let mylabelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.width/2, myView.frame.height/2)

    let myBaseView = UIView()
    myBaseView.frame = myFrame
    myBaseView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.pastelYellowColor()
    myLabel.frame = mylabelFrame

    myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedText("This is my String",20.0,FontValue.FVLight)
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 5
    myLabel.tag = 100
    myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = myLabel.bounds.size.width / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw()
    myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    myLabel.layerborders()

    myBaseView.addSubview(myLabel)

    myBaseView.layerShadow()
    myBaseView.layerGradient()

    myView.addSubview(myBaseView)

    return myLabel
}
```

generic shadow add:

```
func viewshadow<T where T: UIView> (shadowObject: T)
{
    let layer = shadowObject.layer
    let radius = shadowObject.frame.size.width / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw();
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    layer.cornerRadius = radius
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowRadius = 3
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0,2.0)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.shadowColor().CGColor
}
```

view extension for view style:

```
extension UIView {
    func layerborders() {
        let layer = self.layer
        let frame = self.frame
        let myColor = self.backgroundColor
        layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 10.8
        layer.cornerRadius = layer.borderWidth / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw()
    }

    func layerShadow() {
        let layer = self.layer
        let frame = self.frame
        layer.cornerRadius = layer.borderWidth / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw()
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowRadius = 3
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0,2.0)
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.shadowColor().CGColor
    }

    func layerGradient() {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        let size = self.frame.size
        layer.frame.size = size
        layer.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)
        layer.cornerRadius = layer.bounds.size.width / MyConstants.CornerRadius.toRaw();

        var color0 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(250.0/255, 250.0/255, 250.0/255, 0.5)
        var color1 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(200.0/255, 200.0/255, 200.0/255, 0.1)
        var color2 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(150.0/255, 150.0/255, 150.0/255, 0.1)
        var color3 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(100.0/255, 100.0/255, 100.0/255, 0.1)
        var color4 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(50.0/255, 50.0/255, 50.0/255, 0.1)
        var color5 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0/255, 0.0/255, 0.0/255, 0.1)
        var color6 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(150.0/255, 150.0/255, 150.0/255, 0.1)

        layer.colors = [color0,color1,color2,color3,color4,color5,color6]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 2)
    }
}
```

the actual view did load function:

```
func buttonPress (sender:UIButton!) {
    NSLog("%@", "ButtonPressed")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myLabel = myLabelMaker(myView)
    let myButton = myButtonMaker(myView)

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPress:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    viewshadow(myButton)
    viewshadow(myLabel)

}
```

Answer (score 33):

I think, it is a very convenient way to use `regular expressions` to find a range for applying attributes. This is how I did it:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *goodText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:articleText];

NSRange range = [articleText rangeOfString:@"\\[.+?\\]" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [goodText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16] range:range];
    [goodText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor brownColor] range:range];
}

NSString *regEx = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.+?\\s", [self.article.titleText substringToIndex:0]];
range = [articleText rangeOfString:regEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [goodText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:20] range:range];
    [goodText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:range];
}

[self.textView setAttributedText:goodText];
```

I was searching for a list of available attributes and didn't find them here and in a class reference's first page. So I decided to post here information on that.

[Standard Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167)

Attributed strings support the following standard attributes for text. If the key is not in the dictionary, then use the default values described below.

```
NSString *NSFontAttributeName;
NSString *NSParagraphStyleAttributeName;
NSString *NSForegroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName;
NSString *NSSuperscriptAttributeName;
NSString *NSBackgroundColorAttributeName;
NSString *NSAttachmentAttributeName;
NSString *NSLigatureAttributeName;
NSString *NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName;
NSString *NSKernAttributeName;
NSString *NSLinkAttributeName;
NSString *NSStrokeWidthAttributeName;
NSString *NSStrokeColorAttributeName;
NSString *NSUnderlineColorAttributeName;
NSString *NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName;
NSString *NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName;
NSString *NSShadowAttributeName;
NSString *NSObliquenessAttributeName;
NSString *NSExpansionAttributeName;
NSString *NSCursorAttributeName;
NSString *NSToolTipAttributeName;
NSString *NSMarkedClauseSegmentAttributeName;
NSString *NSWritingDirectionAttributeName;
NSString *NSVerticalGlyphFormAttributeName;
NSString *NSTextAlternativesAttributeName;
```

[NSAttributedString programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036i)

A full class reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks for listing the attribute keys (so hard to find otherwise)

Comment: How would you do this in Swift?

Answer (score 29):

This solution will work for any length

```
NSString *strFirst = @"Anylengthtext";
NSString *strSecond = @"Anylengthtext";
NSString *strThird = @"Anylengthtext";

NSString *strComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",strFirst,strSecond,strThird];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strComplete];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
              value:[UIColor redColor]
              range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strFirst]];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
              value:[UIColor yellowColor]
              range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strSecond]];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
              value:[UIColor blueColor]
              range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strThird]];


self.lblName.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Note that for SWIFT, you need to use NSString still, because of the ranges, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27041376/1736679

Answer (score 15):

I wrote helper to add attributes easily:

```
- (void)addColor:(UIColor *)color substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addUnderlineForSubstring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addStrikeThrough:(int)thickness substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addShadowColor:(UIColor *)color width:(int)width height:(int)height radius:(int)radius substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(int)fontSize substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addAlignment:(NSTextAlignment)alignment substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addColorToRussianText:(UIColor *)color;
- (void)addStrokeColor:(UIColor *)color thickness:(int)thickness substring:(NSString *)substring;
- (void)addVerticalGlyph:(BOOL)glyph substring:(NSString *)substring;
```

https://github.com/shmidt/MASAttributes

You can install through CocoaPods also : `pod 'MASAttributes', '~> 1.0.0'`

Answer (score 11):

Since iOS 7 you can use `NSAttributedString` with HTML syntax:

```
NSURL *htmlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  URLForResource: @"string"     withExtension:@"html"];
NSAttributedString *stringWithHTMLAttributes = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:htmlString
                                                                                       options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                                            documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                         error:nil];
textView.attributedText = stringWithHTMLAttributes;// you can use a label also
```

You have to add the file "string.html" to you project, and the content of the html can be like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Avenir, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .red {
        color: red;
      }
      .green {
        color: green;
      }
      .blue {
        color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="red">first</span><span class="green">second</span><span class="blue">third</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, you can use `NSAttributedString` as you want, even without HTML file, like for example:

```
//At the top of your .m file
#define RED_OCCURENCE -red_occurence-
#define GREEN_OCCURENCE -green_occurence-
#define BLUE_OCCURENCE -blue_occurence-
#define HTML_TEMPLATE @"<span style=\"color:red\">-red_occurence-</span><span style=\"color:green\">-green_occurence-</span><span style=\"color:blue\">-blue_occurence-</span></body></html>"

//Where you need to use your attributed string
NSString *string = [HTML_TEMPLATE stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:RED_OCCURENCE withString:@"first"] ;
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:GREEN_OCCURENCE   withString:@"second"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:BLUE_OCCURENCE    withString:@"third"];

NSData* cData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSAttributedString *stringWithHTMLAttributes = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:cData
                                                                                options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                                        documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                     error:nil];
textView.attributedText = stringWithHTMLAttributes;
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 10):

I always found working with attributed strings to be an incredibly long winded and tedious process.

So I made a Mac App that creates all the code for you.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/attributed-string-creator/id730928349?mt=12

Comment: Also here is a category/Blog post for making NSAttributed string a bit easier.  http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/nsattributedstring-creation-helpers/

Answer (score 3):

An easier solution with attributed string extension.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    // this function attaches color to string    
    func setColorForText(textToFind: String, withColor color: UIColor) {
        let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
        self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}
```

Try this and see (Tested in Swift 3 & 4)

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 100, width: 200, height: 30)
let first = "first"
let second = "second"
let third = "third"
let stringValue = "\(first)\(second)\(third)"  // or direct assign single string value like "firstsecondthird"

let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColorForText(textToFind: first, withColor: UIColor.red)   // use variable for string "first"
attributedString.setColorForText(textToFind: "second", withColor: UIColor.green) // or direct string like this "second"
attributedString.setColorForText(textToFind: third, withColor: UIColor.blue)
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Here is expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4:

```
let string:NSMutableAttributedString = {

    let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "firstsecondthird")

    mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red , range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
    mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.green , range: NSRange(location: 5, length: 6))
    mutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue , range: NSRange(location: 11, length: 5))
    return mutableString
}()

print(string)
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: I am trying to give answer in Swift. I accepted its duplicate. Not expecting up votes

Comment: Apologies. I have removed the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can load an `HTML` attributed string in `Swift` as follow

```
   var Str = NSAttributedString(
   data: htmlstring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true),
   options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
   documentAttributes: nil,
   error: nil)

   label.attributedText = Str
```

To load a `html` from file

```
   if let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rtfdoc", withExtension: "rtf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil) {

   let attributedString = NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.editable = false
    }
```

http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2013/11/creating-nsattributedstring-from-html.html

And setup string as per your required attribute....follow this..
http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/

Answer (score 2):

I made a library that makes this a lot easier.  Check out [ZenCopy.](https://github.com/trifl/ZenCopy)

You can create Style objects, and/or set them to keys to reference later. Like this:

```
ZenCopy.manager.config.setStyles {
    return [
        "token": Style(
            color: .blueColor(), // optional
            // fontName: "Helvetica", // optional
            fontSize: 14 // optional
        )
    ]
}
```

Then, you can easily construct strings AND style them AND have params :)

```
label.attributedText = attributedString(
                                ["$0 ".style("token") "is dancing with ", "$1".style("token")], 
                          args: ["JP", "Brock"]
)
```

You can also style things easily with regex searches!

```
let atUserRegex = "(@[A-Za-z0-9_]*)"
mutableAttributedString.regexFind(atUserRegex, addStyle: "token")
```

This will style all words with '@' in front of it with the 'token' style. (e.g. @jpmcglone)

I need to still get it working w/ everything `NSAttributedString` has to offer, but I think `fontName`, `fontSize` and color cover the bulk of it.  Expect lots of updates soon :)

I can help you get started with this if you need. Also looking for feedback, so if it makes your life easier, I'd say mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)changeColorWithString:(UILabel *)uilabel stringToReplace:(NSString *) stringToReplace uiColor:(UIColor *) uiColor{
    NSMutableAttributedString *text =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithAttributedString: uilabel.attributedText];

    [text addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:uiColor range:[uilabel.text rangeOfString:stringToReplace]];

    [uilabel setAttributedText: text];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve such kind of problems I created library in swift which is called Atributika.

```
let str = "<r>first</r><g>second</g><b>third</b>".style(tags:
        Style("r").foregroundColor(.red),
        Style("g").foregroundColor(.green),
        Style("b").foregroundColor(.blue)).attributedString

label.attributedText = str
```

You can find it here https://github.com/psharanda/Atributika

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let combination = NSMutableAttributedString()

var part1 = NSMutableAttributedString()
var part2 = NSMutableAttributedString()
var part3 = NSMutableAttributedString()

let attrRegular = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Palatino-Roman", size: 15)]

let attrBold:Dictionary = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Raleway-SemiBold", size: 15)]

let attrBoldWithColor: Dictionary = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Raleway-SemiBold", size: 15),
                                 NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

if let regular = attrRegular as? [NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject]{
    part1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "first", attributes: regular)

}
if let bold = attrRegular as? [NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject]{
    part2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "second", attributes: bold)
}

if let boldWithColor = attrBoldWithColor as? [NSAttributedStringKey : NSObject]{
    part3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "third", attributes: boldWithColor)
}

combination.append(part1)
combination.append(part2)
combination.append(part3)
```

**Attributes list please see here** [NSAttributedStringKey on Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey)

Answer (score 0):

Super easy way to do this.

```
let text = "This is a colorful attributed string"
let attributedText = 
NSMutableAttributedString.getAttributedString(fromString: text)
attributedText.apply(color: .red, subString: "This")
//Apply yellow color on range
attributedText.apply(color: .yellow, onRange: NSMakeRange(5, 4))
```

For more detail click here;
https://github.com/iOSTechHub/AttributedString