# UITextView formatting with fontname and bold

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

In a UITextView is it possible to set the fontname and then set it to bold?

I know that font name and size can be set using 
fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize

But once this is done how can i make it bold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system font on the iPhone is a good choice for many purposes. You can easily select it in a regular, bold or italic style using built-in font class methods. For example

```
  UIFont *mainTitleFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
  UIFont *subTitleFont = [UIFont SystemFontOfSize:14.0];
  UIFont *textFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
```

But what if you want a font using both bold and italic at the same time, or a different typeface altogether? In that case, you can use the “fontWithName” method as follows.

```
  UIFont *altFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier-Bold" size:14.0];
```

[Reference](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/)

Comment: can we use multiple fonts for one UITextView ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bold variant of the font, e.g. `@"Helvetica-Bold"` as the `fontName`. If using the default system font is ok for you, you can also use `boldSystemFontOfSize:` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:12];
yourTextView.font = f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give font with name then you can refer below link. It have all font which are provided by iOS with their font names.

[iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com/)

Thanks.