# Rich Text Editor ios to load and edit html content for iOS 5 and above

Tags: html, ios, ios5, rich-text-editor

I need to load html data in my view which I will receive from backend for eg:

```
<h2>Title</h2><br>
<p>description here</p>
```

Which will look something like the below image

[image]

I need to edit the contents in the view, lets say add few more paragraph and change the fonts and send the edited content back in html format with the added paragraph and font tags.

How should I go about doing this? I need it to support from iOS 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, some answers here for other readers: [Using iOS 5 rich text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012245/using-ios-5-rich-text-editor)

The Native iOS class to render HTML: **UIWebView**, to edit HTML UIWebView using its delegate: **UiWebViewDelegate**. I have not tested these, nor I have examples.

The best Open Source project I've found so far to render and edit HTML, for iOS7 only:

- https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor

This is the other one that is a basic implementation of CKEditor for iOS:

- https://github.com/insanoid/iOS-HTMLTextEditor

Other Open Source projects: (Use https:// on the pseudo links below)
To edit HTML:

- https://github.com/gfthr/FastTextView
- https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor

... not part of the question, but if you want to Render HTML within your iOS app:

- https://github.com/jonasschnelli/I7CoreTextExample
- https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText
- https://github.com/hulu/GrannySmith

Answer (score -1):

adding two more which is updated and can be used above ios 11 and written in swift

-AztecEditor
[link](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS)

-updated version of 
RichEditorView
[link](https://github.com/Andrew-Chen-Wang/RichEditorView)

Comment: why did this goes negative, it's a helpful link to work on , can any moderator explain this

Comment: it is duplicate answer, you have pasted same answer for multiple questions. Instead you can share your answer link.

Comment: @ArshadShaik i just added two more resource, if you have time , you can check, none of them you will find it in this post, the RichEditorview is updated version of webkit, where the answer is still using the old webview