# String with different font

Tags: iphone, string, fonts

I am having a string message i need first word of that as bold font and rest normal.
Making different label can be create problems,(need to find the size of first the make other and then make other,text is in 4 line).

How can i use NSAttributedString here. I could found [How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

but using this shows undeclared NSForegrou... (present in app kit framework).But could not found app kit framework on sdk 4.2

Need help for making such kind of string(bold + normal text).

Comment: You could use a UIWebView and use HTML to format your text

Comment: how to make a html file at runtime.Also having this text in table row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the below blog tutorial with code, they have different font with `NSAttributedString`.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML

https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor

Answer (score 0):

May I point you to the CoreText Framework and [Befriending Core Text](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) on cocoanetics.com. This will show you how to format text.