# UILabel with text of two different colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, textcolor

I want to display a string like this in a `UILabel`:

> There are 5 results.

Where the number 5 is red in color and the rest of the string is black.

How can I do this in code?

Comment: @EmptyStack This is certainly **not** the case since iOS 4 supports NSAttributedString. See my answer below.

Answer (score 224):

The way to do it is to use `NSAttributedString` like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *text = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
   initWithAttributedString: label.attributedText];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
             value:[UIColor redColor] 
             range:NSMakeRange(10, 1)];
[label setAttributedText: text];
```

I created a `UILabel` [extension to do it](https://github.com/joaoffcosta/UILabel-FormattedText).

Comment: Can I add targets on it. Thnaks

Comment: Nice Category for UILabel. Thanks a lot. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 72):

I have done this by creating a `category` for `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
-(void)setColorForText:(NSString*) textToFind withColor:(UIColor*) color
{
    NSRange range = [self.mutableString rangeOfString:textToFind options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [self addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
- (void) setColoredLabel
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Here is a red blue and green text"];
    [string setColorForText:@"red" withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [string setColorForText:@"blue" withColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [string setColorForText:@"green" withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    mylabel.attributedText = string;
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString{
    func setColorForText(_ textToFind: String, with color: UIColor) {
        let range = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
        }
    }
}
```

USAGE

```
func setColoredLabel() {
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Here is a red blue and green text")
    string.setColorForText("red", with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1))
    string.setColorForText("blue", with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))
    string.setColorForText("green", with: #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1))
    mylabel.attributedText = string
}
```

**SWIFT 4** @kj13 Thanks for notifying

```
// If no text is send, then the style will be applied to full text
func setColorForText(_ textToFind: String?, with color: UIColor) {

    let range:NSRange?
    if let text = textToFind{
        range = self.mutableString.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive)
    }else{
        range = NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
    }
    if range!.location != NSNotFound {
        addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range!)
    }
}
```

**I have did more experiments with attributes and below are the results, here is the** [SOURCECODE](https://github.com/anoop4real/UILabelStyles)

Here is the result

[image: Styles]

Comment: You need to create a new Category for NSMutableAttributedString with the method...anyways I added this sample to github, you can grab and check it https://github.com/anoop4real/NSMutableAttributedString-Color

Comment: But i need to set the color of all alphabet  with incasesensitive  in a string ....like  all  "e" in red color of the whole string

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableAttributedString' declares the selector 'setColorForText:withColor:'

Comment: I got error 'Use of unresolved identifier 'NSForegroundColorAttributeName' with Swift4.1, but I replace 'NSForegroundColorAttributeName' to 'NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor' and building correctly.

Comment: @kj13 Thanks for notifying, I updated the answer and added a few more styles

Comment: Swift 4.2: `addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value:NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue, range: range!)` BTW, this control is brilliant!

Answer (score 26):

Here you go

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lblTemp.text];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];
lblTemp.attributedText = string;
```

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 4**

```
// An attributed string extension to achieve colors on text.
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
       let range: NSRange = self.mutableString.range(of: stringValue, options: .caseInsensitive)
       self.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
    }

}

// Try it with label
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 100, width: 260, height: 30)
let stringValue = "There are 5 results."
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
attributedString.setColor(color: UIColor.red, forText: "5")
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26)
label.attributedText = attributedString
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

*Result*

[image]

**Swift 3**

```
func setColoredLabel() {
        var string: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "redgreenblue")
        string.setColor(color: UIColor.redColor(), forText: "red")
        string.setColor(color: UIColor.greenColor(), forText: "green")
        string.setColor(color: UIColor.blueColor(, forText: "blue")
        mylabel.attributedText = string
    }


func setColor(color: UIColor, forText stringValue: String) {
        var range: NSRange = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(stringValue, options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)
        if range != nil {
            self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

```
//NSString *myString = @"I have to replace text 'Dr Andrew Murphy, John Smith' ";
NSString *myString = @"Not a member?signin";

//Create mutable string from original one
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];

//Fing range of the string you want to change colour
//If you need to change colour in more that one place just repeat it
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"signin"];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:(63/255.0) green:(163/255.0) blue:(158/255.0) alpha:1.0] range:range];

//Add it to the label - notice its not text property but it's attributeText
_label.attributedText = attString;
```

Comment: Good solution especially for localized strings. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Since **iOS 6**, UIKit supports drawing attributed strings, so no extension or replacement is needed.

From `UILabel`:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText;
```

You just need to build up your `NSAttributedString`. There are basically two ways:

1. Append chunks of text with the same attributes - for each part create one `NSAttributedString` instance and append them to one `NSMutableAttributedString`
2. Create attributed text from plain string and then add attributed for given ranges – find the range of your number (or whatever) and apply different color attribute on that.

Answer (score 7):

Anups answer in swift. Can be reused from any class.

In swift file

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setColorForStr(textToFind: String, color: UIColor) {

        let range = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(textToFind, options:NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch);
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range);
        }

    }
}
```

In Some view controller

```
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.labelShopInYourNetwork.text!);
attributedString.setColorForStr("YOUR NETWORK", color: UIColor(red: 0.039, green: 0.020, blue: 0.490, alpha: 1.0));
self.labelShopInYourNetwork.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 4):

Having a UIWebView or more than one UILabel could be considered overkill for this situation.

My suggestion would be to use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which is a drop-in replacement for UILabel that supports [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This means you can very easily apply differents styles to different ranges in a string.

Answer (score 4):

For displaying short, formatted text that doesn't need to be editable, [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the way to go. There are several open-source projects for labels that use [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003622) and Core Text for rendering. See [CoreTextAttributedLabel](https://github.com/umerh/CoreTextAttributedLabel) or [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) for example.

Answer (score 4):

My answer has also the option to color all the occurrence of a text not only one occurrence of it : "wa ba wa ba dubdub" , you can color all the occurrence of wa not only the first occurrence like the accepted answer.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString{
    func setColorForText(_ textToFind: String, with color: UIColor) {
        let range = self.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: range)
        }
    }

    func setColorForAllOccuranceOfText(_ textToFind: String, with color: UIColor) {
        let inputLength = self.string.count
        let searchLength = textToFind.count
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length)

        while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            range = (self.string as NSString).range(of: textToFind, options: [], range: range)
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                self.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: color, range: NSRange(location: range.location, length: searchLength))
                range = NSRange(location: range.location + range.length, length: inputLength - (range.location + range.length))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do this :

```
let message = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "wa ba wa ba dubdub")
message.setColorForText(subtitle, with: UIColor.red) 
// or the below one if you want all the occurrence to be colored 
message.setColorForAllOccuranceOfText("wa", with: UIColor.red) 
// then you set this attributed string to your label :
lblMessage.attributedText = message
```

Comment: And how can I use it?

Comment: Updated my answer, have a nice day :)

Comment: Great! This should be higher up!

Answer (score 3):

`NSAttributedString` is the way to go. The following question has a great answer that shows you how to do it [How do you use NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 3):

[JTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTAttributedLabel/) (by mystcolor) lets you use the attributed string support in UILabel under iOS 6 and at the same time its JTAttributedLabel class under iOS 5 through its JTAutoLabel.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 and above:** Inspired by [anoop4real's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863856/3659227), here's a String extension that can be used to generate text with 2 different colors.

```
extension String {

    func attributedStringForPartiallyColoredText(_ textToFind: String, with color: UIColor) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let mutableAttributedstring = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        let range = mutableAttributedstring.mutableString.range(of: textToFind, options: .caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            mutableAttributedstring.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
        }
        return mutableAttributedstring
    }
}
```

Following example changes color of asterisk to red while retaining original label color for remaining text.

```
label.attributedText = "Enter username *".attributedStringForPartiallyColoredText("*", with: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Swift 3.0 solution

```
extension UILabel{


    func setSubTextColor(pSubString : String, pColor : UIColor){
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!);
        let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: pSubString, options:NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: pColor, range: range);
        }
        self.attributedText = attributedString

    }
}
```

And there is an example of call :

```
let colorString = " (string in red)"
self.mLabel.text = "classic color" + colorString
self.mLabel.setSubTextColor(pSubString: colorString, pColor: UIColor.red)
```

Comment: Hi, how do I do this if I want to add two different colorStrings? I tried using your example and just add another one, but it still only colors one of them..

Comment: Try this :

let colorString = " (string in red)"
let colorStringGreen = " (string in green)"
self.mLabel.text = "classic color" + colorString +  colorStringGreen
self.mLabel.setSubTextColor(pSubString: colorString, pColor: UIColor.red)
self.mLabel.setSubTextColor(pSubString: colorStringGreen, pColor: UIColor.green)

Comment: This is strange, it still doesn't change both: https://s24.postimg.org/ds0rpyyut/Screen_Shot_2017_01_21_at_19_52_51.png.

Comment: A problem is that if the two strings are the same, it only colors one of them, look here: http://pastebin.com/FJZJTpp3. You have a fix for this aswell?

Answer (score 2):

For **Xamarin** users I have a static **C#** method where I pass in an array of strings, an array of UIColours and array of UIFonts (they will need to match in length). The attributed string is then passed back.

see:

```
public static NSMutableAttributedString GetFormattedText(string[] texts, UIColor[] colors, UIFont[] fonts) {

  NSMutableAttributedString attrString = new NSMutableAttributedString(string.Join("", texts));
  int position = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++) {
    attrString.AddAttribute(new NSString("NSForegroundColorAttributeName"), colors[i], new NSRange(position, texts[i].Length));

    var fontAttribute = new UIStringAttributes {
      Font = fonts[I]
    };

    attrString.AddAttributes(fontAttribute, new NSRange(position, texts[i].Length));

    position += texts[i].Length;
  }

  return attrString;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using Xcode 10.1. There is a option of switching between plain text and Attributed text in Label text in Interface Builder


[image]

Hope this may help someone else..!

Comment: It looks like XCode 11.0 broke the Attributed Text editor. So, I tried using TextEdit to create the text then pasted it into Xcode and it worked surprisingly well.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UILabel{

    func setSubTextColor(pSubString : String, pColor : UIColor){


        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = self.attributedText != nil ? NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText!) : NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!);


        let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: pSubString, options:NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: pColor, range: range);
        }
        self.attributedText = attributedString

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was created a method like the next one:

```
-(void)setColorForText:(NSString*) textToFind originalText:(NSString *)originalString withColor:(UIColor*)color andLabel:(UILabel *)label{

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:originalString];
NSRange range = [originalString rangeOfString:textToFind];

[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];

label.attributedText = attString;

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
}
label.attributedText = attString; }
```

It worked with just one different color in the same text but you can adapt it easily to more colores in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

By using below code you can set multiple colors based on word.

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 ball",@"2 ball",@"3 ball",@"4 ball", nil];    
NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
for (NSString * str in array)
 {
    NSMutableAttributedString * textstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,",str] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[self getRandomColor]}];
     [attStr appendAttributedString:textstr];
  }
UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 300, 30)];
lab.attributedText = attStr;
[self.view addSubview:lab];

-(UIColor *) getRandomColor
{
   CGFloat redcolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
   CGFloat greencolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
   CGFloat bluencolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
   return  [UIColor colorWithRed:redcolor green:greencolor blue:bluencolor alpha:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SwiftRichString`](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftRichString) works perfect! You can use `+` to concatenate two attributed string