# How use Different color in same label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

The problem that i am going to write it already solved using two `UILabel`.i am searching some optimize way.
I have a string `(example : hello world )` that need to show in an `UILabel` with different color.like `"hello in red color " and "world in green color"`

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel with text of two different colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iOS 6, `UILabel` has an `attributedText` property. Assign an appropriate `NSAttributedString` with your desired content and formatting attributes to this property and you're done. The easiest way to do this is in Interface Builder, where you just have to switch your label's text from "Plain" to "Attributed". After doing this, you can set the formatting attributes directly in IB.

(As I said, this solution works only in iOS 6.0+)

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose that you have a text label named coloredLabel, and you want to write hello in red and world in green.
From iOS 6 you can create an attributed string and set it as attributed text of your label:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString* str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: @"Hello world"];
    [str setAttributes: @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] }  range: NSMakeRange(0, 5) ];
    [str setAttributes: @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor] }  range: NSMakeRange(6, 5) ];
    coloredLabel.attributedText= str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for backwards compatibility with iOS 4, you can use `NIAttributedLabel` from Nimbus.
http://nimbuskit.info/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can also set color with image pattern like bellow..

```
UIColor *LableColor=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel is the way to go if you need to target lower than iOS 6 !