# Multicolor text in UILabel

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need a label (UILabel using MonoTouch) that will contain a two colour text `<blue>BlueText</blue> <black>BlackText</black>` you got the point. I tried the following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString titleString = new NSMutableAttributedString("Party Vama is pending for your confirmation");
titleString.AddAttribute (new NSString(@"TextColor"), 
                          UIColor.FromRGB(20, 125, 240), 
                          new NSRange(0,5));
titleString.AddAttribute (new NSString (@"Font"), 
                          fontx.WithSize (100), 
                          new NSRange (0, 10));
confirmationTitle.AttributedText = titleString;`
```

Where confirmationTitle is the UILabel
The code doesn't show any errors but the text is one colour only and at the same size.

Comment: Try this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors

Comment: I also tried NSForegroundColorAttributeName and I have the same result.