# How to change font size of a second word in String

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have one string:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit"

I need to change  font size of "`ipsum`".

Anybody know how can i change the font size of specific word in string.

Comment: you should use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors 
Possible Duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *string = 
                              [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithString: @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit"];



[string addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                  value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:24]
                  range: NSMakeRange(7,5)];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `NSAttributedString`.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit"];
[myString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont  systemFontOfSize:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(7, 5)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit"];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(7, 5)];
```

Comment: While working code examples is good, it helps if you can add some more description as to what it is doing and why so that people reading it can understand.