# How to set different colors for each word(dynamic words getting from server) in label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have multiple words in an array:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 ball",@"2 ball",@"3 ball",@"4 ball", nil];
```

I need to set these words into `UILabel` with different colors.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel with text of two different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501808/uilabel-with-text-of-two-different-colors)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - in this they tried with static word, But in my case i have dynamic words.

Comment: @Haric - I am not asked this show your tried code

Comment: @pawan i want  different  colors with dynamic words.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - thanks for your kind support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Swift you can use below code.

```
import UIKit
var str = ["Hi", "Hello", "I", "am", "Prabhu"]
var newStr : [NSAttributedString] = []
var newS = NSMutableAttributedString()

func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{
  let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
  let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
  let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
  return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}

for s in str {
  let newString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: s + ",", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : getRandomColor()])
  newS.append(newString)
}

print(newS)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Hari can you try below code

```
 NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 ball",@"2 ball",@"3 ball",@"4 ball", nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
for (NSString * str in array)
 {
        NSMutableAttributedString * textstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,",str] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName :[self getRandomColor]}];
        [attStr appendAttributedString:textstr];
 }

UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 300, 300, 30)];
lab.attributedText = attStr;
[self.view addSubview:lab];



-(UIColor *) getRandomColor
{
    CGFloat redcolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat greencolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat bluencolor = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    return  [UIColor colorWithRed:redcolor green:greencolor blue:bluencolor alpha:1.0];
}
```