# How to assign NSString UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uicolor

Is there a way I can assign UIColor to NSString like in

```
cell.textLabel.text = [UIColor grayColor];
```

I am trying to add color for following string like :

```
NSString *text = @"Hello"
[text setColor:[UIColor grayColor]; // It gives error here saying it cannot assign
```

Is there any other way I can assign color to NSString ?

Answer (score 7):

NSString is just a string of characters. It doesn't have a color, font, weight, size, style or anything — just characters. You'll want to use [NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring) instead.

But bear in mind that NSAttributedString isn't an NSString — it's basically a lightweight container that pairs a string with a dictionary of attributes and provides appropriate drawing code. In particular, you can't pass an NSAttributedString to an API that expects a string. You either have to have an API that takes an NSAttributedString or be drawing the string yourself.

Comment: NSForegroundColorAttributeName is undeclared. Can we use it ?

Comment: @lifemoveson: You'll want to use the Core Text equivalent, `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`. As noted in the iOS NSAttributedString docs, it's mainly used with Core Text.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a color to a string. A string doesn't have data about color. You can assign a color to a label, like

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

You have to wait until you display the string to set the color. If you need to, you can store the color in a variable of type UIColor * until later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the color on the string, you set it on the label. The string is just a sequence of characters - the label is responsible for displaying it and so controls things like color.

Take a look at [UILabel class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) and look for the textColor property.

In your example, I think you want:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

1.Above is a link 4 files from github which u download and place it in your project folder.

2.Then #import "NSAttributedString+Attributes.h" in you .m file.

3.Now u can change your string color, font, size etc. like below.

```
NSString *prev = @"Name: ";

NSMutableAttributedString *now = [NSMutableAttributedString  attributedStringWithString:prev];

[now setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[now setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:24]];
```