# Underline text inside uitextview

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextview

How can i underline text inside uitextview programmatically?

Comment: i get undeclared error for using NSForegroundColorAttributeName. pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSAttributedString for this purpose.
Following is link for the same - https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes

And you can refer this thread to check how to use NSAttributedString.
[How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 0):

I used UIWebView instead of UITextView to solve this problem.

```
NSString *contentHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><font color=\"white\" size=\"4\"><table width=\"260px\"><tr><td align=\"left\" width=\"160px\"><u>Left:</u></td><td align=\"right\" width=\"100px\">315</td></tr></table></font></body></html>"];
[listWebView loadHTMLString:contentHtml baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [self.textView.attributedText mutableCopy];   
int valueToSet = kCTUnderlineStyleSingle;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:valueToSet] range:CGMakeRange(0, self.textView.text.length)];

self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
[attributedString release];
```