# Displaying NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have the below code in my app

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.myDisplayTxt];
      [string addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName 
                     value:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]
                     range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];

    self.myTextView.text = string;
```

When assigning the NSMutableAttributedString to UITextView I get the following error:

> Incompatible objective c types struct NSMutableAttributedString 
>   expected struct nsstring

So please let me know, how can I display the NSMutableAttributedString in UITextView.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use some library to do that. As omz wrote, the UITextView does not unfortunatelly support the `NSAttributedString`.

Maybe this one can help you: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView

They say about this library the following:

> UITextView replacement with additional support for NSAttributedString.

**UPDATE:** Based on your clarification in the comment for omz's answer, you can look here:
[Underline text inside uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309609/underline-text-inside-uitextview)

**UPDATE 2:** In **iOS 6** you can use the NSAttributedString out of the box. For example like this:

```
UIColor *_red=[UIColor redColor];
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:72.0f];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
[attString addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:_red range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
[attString addAttribute:NSStrokeWidthAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
```

Comment: This is out of date, UITextView does now support NSAttributedString

Comment: @Frank Really... downvote? :) Just beacuse the answer is not uptodate anymore? And what about  supporting older versions of iOS? Still not usable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, `UITextView` doesn't support attributed strings. If you really only want to use attributed strings to set the foreground color (as in your example), you could achieve the same by setting the text view's `textColor` property.

Comment: With `UITextView`, no. As @Ondra pointed out, there are a couple of third-party alternatives to `UITextView` that support rich text (attributed strings), but from my experience, they tend to be buggy and incomplete - ymmv.

Comment: As of iOS 6, `UITextView`s support `NSAttributedStrings`.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign attributed string via `UITextView.attributedText` property. `UITextView.text` accepts `NSString` or plain text only.

```
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

See documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/attributedText