# UITextview dataDetectorTypeAddress - Map opened in different application

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I just came to know about an awesome ios feature for UITextViews i.e [UITextview dataDetectorTypes](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-clickable-hyperlinks-from-a-url-phone-number-or-address.html). It is really useful to display text as links.

However, I noticed one thing. When the string is a physical address, Google Map is opened which is appropriate, but in a different application.

Is there any way we can open that google map in our application and not go into default iOS application wherein map is opened? So that I can go back into my application from the map. Is there any delegate method which can control this? Right now I have to minimize the application(make it run in background) and again open it which does not looks good.

Comment: How to do that? Can you guide me? The address type is at the last in the link above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question earlier. I am not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another solution for your problem.

If you use dataDetectorTypes, the link is alway opened in built-in app firstly.

You can make your action with button and custom string as below:

- push your text into an UIButton.
- make your text displayed as link with  NSAtributedSring as this question, use UIButton instead of UITextView:

[Underline text inside uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309609/underline-text-inside-uitextview)

- make action for your button when user click on it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy, you'll need to subclass `UIApplication`, override it's `openURL:` and pass the application class name to the target's `main.m` `int main(...)` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

intercepting the urls you can return `NO` for `maps:` schemes not to launch the `Maps` app and handle the address in whatever way you wish.

---

1. In the project create a new class subclassing `UIApplication`
2. Add the following method to be overridden:

   -(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url 
   {
       NSLog(@"Open %@", [url absoluteString]);

   ```
   // do something if the url scheme is maps:
   return NO;
   ```

   }
3. In the target's `main.m` file change the default `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` implementation to make it to use your `UIApplication` class, it should look like this:

   #import < UIKit/UIKit.h> //remove the leading space to compile

   #import "LXAppDelegate.h"

   #import "LXapp.h"

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {

   ```
   @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
   }
   ```

   }

That's not for `ARC` (i'm never using it), refer to the [UIApplicationMain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain) documentation to understand what happens and what should be probably changed for ARC support.

Comment: This is a little confusing at fist but makes sense in the end. There are probably a lot of other useful things you can do with a subclassed UIApplicaiton.

Comment: @T. Markle i hope that's understandable, if so i can also suggest to consider subclassing UIWindow, you can use it to create the key application window at application delegate. That is useful to intercept `sendEvent` method allowing you to process the remote controls and window touch actions.