# How to connect Layar actions to my customViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller, layar

**This is my situation:**

I created a layer that find Vision-POIs and I integrated the iPhone Layar Player SDK into my iPhone app.

When I find a POI I get an icon "info" on the POI framed.
Clicking on the icon I want to connect it to a view controller that i created to show the details for this POI.

How can i set the URI actions to link the icon to a view controller?
In the documentation there are no examples that show this case.

http://layar.com/documentation/browser/api/getpois-response/actions/#actions-uri

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2):

You can not connect directly your Layar with a ViewController. It´s impossible to join a POI in Layar with your ViewController. You can connect a POI with a Website, a video, a sound,...
If you want to play with ViewControllers and Augmented Reality, I'd advise you to use [Metaio SDK](http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/). It´s free with the watermark and you can do more than with Layar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the SDK and unfortunately the [actions documentation](http://www.layar.com/documentation/browser/api/getpois-response/actions/) is obviously outdated. However assuming the documentation is correct, you must be able to send the request to the wrapping application and intercept it at `UIApplication` `openURL:` and pass the URL parameters to your show-info method (see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780545/uitextview-datadetectortypeaddress-map-opened-in-different-application/10780894#10780894) for details).