# How to set color for EGOTextview

Tags: iphone, ios, textview

I am creating `TextView` based application. In my application I want to create multicolor text with different font in a single `textview` so that I have preferred `EGOTextView`. By using `egotextview`, I have changed the font but I dont how to change text color. How can I set color for `EGOTextview` please suggest me some tips.

Comment: [self setTextColor:color range:range];

Answer (score 1):

`EGOTextView` has support for `NSAttributedString`, you can use it to change the color of the text, as long as many other properties, check this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring) for more details.