# How to give stroke color and shining effect to text entered in uitextfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I need to give stroke and shinny effect to text entered in `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSAttributedString` to set customize the text in UITextField, the below link may help you how to use `NSAttributedString`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring

You can set NSAttributedString to UITextField like this: textField.attributedText = someAttributedText (where someAttributedText is a type of `NSAttributedString`)

Answer (score 0):

Create the "effect" image you'd like in `PhotoShop` or any other photo editing software.

Put a `UIImage` on top of the `UITextField`.

Set the `UIImage` to the effect image you created. If the transparency is set correctly you should get that effect on top of the `UITextfield` you want.