# Change color within string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know how to change the colour of substring within a string.
So for example, I have the following original black colour substring:

```
NSString *original=@"Frank Megan Timmy
                    Marcus Andrea Matt
                   Jamie Lauren Marcus";
```

Let us assume that the user has done something and I would like to make Marcus Andrea Matt a RED colour (for example) within the original string and keep everything else the same.

Can anyone tell me how this can do be done?

Comment: `NSAttributedString`

Comment: @Mar0ux Thank you for the reply! Can you please explain how or provide an example? Much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3482346/1704346

Comment: @Teddy13 :) at least attempt a solution/read the documentation/search before asking for code. Also, pl don't ask for code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Frank Megan Timmy Marcus Andrea Matt Jamie Lauren Marcus"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,18)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(18,18)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(36,20)];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 80)];
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setAttributedText:string];

[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString` to do this.
Change the type of `original` to `NSMutableAttributedString` and use

```
[original addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:yourRange];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution:

```
NSString *original=@"Frank Megan Timmy
                    Marcus Andrea Matt
                   Jamie Lauren Marcus";
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:original];
/ now we only change the color of "Frank"
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```