# How to highlight searched text in UITableView rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, uisearchbar, highlight

I have a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar` associated with it. I want to highlight the searched string if it is a substring in the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're done with searching within `UITableView` if so then to highlight the result you've two options,

If you're targeting iOS 6.0 and higher then there's one `NSAttributedString` [**see the doc here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can **bold**, *colored* or even apply `different fonts` for the substring within a string something like,

> This is an *example* of **highlighted** `text`

Check this, [How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

Or if you also want to support iOS 6 previous versions then you have to use attributed labels to highlight your search, some well implemented labels are,

1) [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)

2) [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

> If you've not implemented searching in UITableView yet then [here's an example](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/12/table-search-display-tutorial.html).