# How to show multiple line text that has different font without using multiple Labels

Tags: ios

I have to show a text paragraph that contains few words in bold font. ex.

[image]

If I use different labels then on changing the orientation it does not resize properly.

Can anyone tell me what can the best way to do it.

Comment: use attributed string with different fonts and put it in single label by setting number of lines

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `NSAttributedString` and assign it to the `UITextField`, this is an example:

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];

NSMutableAttributedString *myAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
[myAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:boldFont
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[myAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                      value:regularFont
                      range:NSMakeRange(3, 5)];
[self.description setAttributedText:myAttributedString];
```

Find all the doc here:

[NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an UITextView using `NSAttributedString` (have a look to the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

And you have an explanation of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring).

You can find the range of your word and change the font or the color or whatever using :

```
- (IBAction)colorWord:(id)sender {
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.text.text];

    NSArray *words = [self.text.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for (NSString *word in words) 
    {        
        if ([word hasPrefix:@"@"]) 
        {
            NSRange range=[self.text.text rangeOfString:word];
            [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];           
        }
    }
    [self.text setAttributedText:string];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. don't hesitate to valid the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use a webView and load it with your string:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style=\"background-color: transparent;\">This is <b><i>Test</b></i> dummy text ..</body></html>"] baseURL:nil];
```