# Placing PlaceHolder In TextField

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

I want to add mandatory field mark in textfield placeholder text like below image please suggest me i am totally confused how to do it

[image]

Comment: Please explain what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attriButedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Mandatory*"];
[attriButedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                         value:[NSColor lightGrayColor] 
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, 9)];
[attriButedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                         value:[NSColor redColor] 
                         range:NSMakeRange(9, 1)];
[[self.textField cell] setPlaceholderAttributedString:attriButedString];
```

This will look like as:

[image]

**Note**: Instead of hard-coded range you can calculate according to your stringlength.

Comment: Good One anoop sir :)plus 1

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you are creating TextField from xib click on text field and go to attribute inspecter and fill your placeholder name in placeholder text feild

Comment: in that case you have to make your textfeild programmitically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring chek this this will help you

Comment: no yaar. You need to color the placeholderString, as in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.....

```
 [tfSubject setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:88.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```