# change placeholder colour while validating text field

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I want to change the placeholder colour as red when I left the text field as empty (for example...placeholder of first text field will be changed to read while I left the first text field and starting to enter in the second text field..)

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340224/iphone-uitextfield-change-placeholder-text-color

Comment: You need to use `NSAttributedString`. after validation fails change the color of the string. you can take help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423541/placing-placeholder-in-textfield/20423592#20423592)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSAttributedString`. after validation fails change the color of the string.

```
-(void)methodForValidation{
   ... //code for validation
   if(validationFail){
        NSMutableAttributedString *attriButedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:yourStringHere"];
        [attriButedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                                 value:[NSColor redColor] 
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, lengthOfYourString)];

        [[self.yourTextField cell] setPlaceholderAttributedString:attriButedString];
   }
}
```