# Different Text sizes in the same text view

Tags: ios, uitextview

In my app, I have a UITextview. The data is populated from the DB to this textview. The issue I am having is trivial but not sure how to solve this. The data is a sentence with a time stamp.

For example

Today is new year. Happy New year.
Updated at 1-Jan -2014 12:00 PM

I wish the time stamp (i.e. Updated at 1-Jan -2014 12:00 PM) to be appear in a smaller font size than the sentence. Could anyone please help me how to accomplish this task.

The code is below

```
 NSString *messagetext=[[NSString alloc]init];
 NSString *messagetextwotimestamp=[[NSString alloc]init];
 messagetext=[self getMessageOnefromDB];



 NSString *storytext=messagetext;
 CGSize StoryTextSize = [storytext sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Myriad Pro" size:16.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(254, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    messageOne.frame=CGRectMake(40, 230, 235, StoryTextSize.height+25);
    messageOne.text=messagetext;
    [messageOne setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15.0f]];
```

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: If the data is static, as in, your users can not edit it, just use 2 different `UILabel`s (not editable) rather than text views(editable)

Comment: Thanks. The textview is readonly and not editable. Is there a way of setting 2 text sizes in a single textview. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for **NSAttributedString**. Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also, look at this question: ["How to use NSAttributedString"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring).