# How to use CSS in NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone, ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have html file which i am loading through below code

```
NSURL *htmlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource: @"index2" withExtension:@"html"];
NSAttributedString *stringWithHTMLAttributes = [[NSAttributedString alloc]   initWithFileURL:htmlString options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
UITextView *textView1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
textView1.attributedText=stringWithHTMLAttributes;
```

The problem here is that  textview is not loading css file , 
does `NSAttributedString` string support CSS ?
If yes then please help me how to do it

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: The solution is here, [answered][1] on stackoverflow.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: Can you add the content of your HTML file?  You can also try with this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090597/how-to-add-css-of-an-html-to-nsattributedstring/22178543#22178543)