# Highlight(with color) a substring from a UILabel

Tags: swift, twitter, uicolor

Hi want to highlight a substring from a string.
I'm doing an app for Twitter and I want to highlight the usernames and hashtags and urls.I have the string and the substring captured.All I want is to highlight that substring from the string.

Edit:
The problem is that I don't know how to get the range from that string,because I get that string over Twitter and I don't know it.Help me to get the range

```
 for user in tweet.userMentions{

                let userName:NSString = user.keyword
                var atrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:tweetTextLabel.text!)
                atrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: //myproblem is here)
                tweetTextLabel.text = atrString

                }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use NSAttributedString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

Comment: What is the substring? Right now the Tweet is the only string and you're not using userName variable at all.  Are you trying to highlight a part of the Tweet?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to highlight a part of the tweet(usernames,urls,hashtags)Here it is for user