# Bold Style and Color words in a String loading from .plist file xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

hi i am creating IOS app using some labels which take strings from the property list file. i want **some of my text in a string to be bold style** and **some text to be color**. How can i do that from the plist?

as in android we use **text** to make the text bold in the strind.xml. how can we make this in the plist?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is to use **NSAttributedString**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring) should help

Comment: but i am loading all my strings from .plist. Is there any way to make text bold in a string which i created in .plist

Comment: What you can do is add some tag like <b> or anything in the static string you are putting in .plist file, after that when you fetch it, use the tag (e.g. <b>) to find/replace the string/substring and make a NSAttributedString out of it as per your need. 
As such there is no other methods(of which i'm aware of) available apart from NSAttributed string to customise string.

Comment: You misunderstood.
<b> could be anything, like  <galaxy>, it's not how it's like in html.
You have to explicitly find the tag and make a substring and format it as per your need using NSAttributedString.
I would suggest you to look how to make substring and how to use NSAttributedString. After that use the above concept to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative-

You can divide your string into parts and add into plist as array elements inspite of single string.

Suppose you have a string "Hello i'm no one".

Instead of making it one, divide it in into 2 or 3 parts according to need and add as array items.

In code, get the strings as array items and add with labels.
Now you can have 2 or 3 label according to your string requirements. Make one bold, make other different its upto you.

Just an alternative cheers