# How to display hashtag with diffrent font in UITextField in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, hashtag

I have textfield in which user will enter some hashtags.When user is typing the hashtag if the then it should be displayed with a diffrent font style.Tetxt field should accept only hashtags not any other string value in the textfield & also i want to the number of tags in an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look in to ´NSAttributedString´ class.

Comment: Can you please explain more.How do i make more of it?

Comment: Read the documentation, experiment, google it. Third hit on google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring seems like a good starting point.