# how to use round corner text in uilabel in iphone

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a label Like,

[image: & text should be like this]

I want to display this single label with different font colors.

i.e..,

"First" string should be in redcolor.

"&" text should be roundcornerd and lightgraycolor.

Answer (score 0):

Use nsattributedstring
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring

Example use 
[How do you use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482346/how-do-you-use-nsattributedstring)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:singlestoreNode.objSeName];
                [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
                [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(2,3)];

               yourlable.attributedText = string;

yourlable.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating 3 labels.

Set the colors for the label like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lblTemp.text];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(5,6)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(11,5)];
lblTemp.attributedText = string;
```

For the round background in "&" you can do the following:

```
[yourUILabel sizeToFit];
yourUILabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
yourUILabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
yourUILabel.layer.cornerRadius = yourUILabel.frame.size.width/2;
```

Then you just need to align everything.

Comment: if you want to have only one UILabel, another solution would be to place a round uivei behind the "&"

Comment: yeah but the size of the label can decrease or increase according to data from server .....thnks for recommding tis